# Is redis JMS-compliant, how to setup jms+redis?

Tags: java, spring, redis, jms, activemq-classic

I have downloaded jms sample from http://spring.io/guides. The sample uses activemq. When I tried to use redis instead of activemq as messaging broker, it reports errors, mainly protocol hand shake errors. My question is: is redis jms compliant? Can I use redis as cache to jms message?
application.properties
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:6379

Comment: Have you seen this? https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-redis/

Comment: I knew it. It doesnt answer my question.

Comment: Your question is approaching this at the wrong angle. JMS is a specification ([JSR-914](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=914), specifically). ActiveMQ provides a Java library that fulfills that specification (e.g. by providing an implementation of `JmsConnectionFactory`). JMS is simply a specification used to standardize the API for message queue (MQ) services. To answer your question more directly: No, Redis does not provide a JMS implementation. But that doesn't mean you can't use it as an MQ, e.g. by using the example implementation in the link I provided.